# Issues regarding image and random row color for a table in openxml?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-office, openxml

I'm using an HTML to OpenXML convertor, gridview HTML code is assigned to a stringbuilder.  Using that we convert that HTML to OpenXML, but when it comes to word the following below issues are found.

1. I have to fill background of a row of a table with grainsboro color but only text background is filled and not cell completely.
2. I wanted to align the image of the header to the right.

This is an asp.net application done in C#

```
A***building image code plz tell me how to align the image to right***
d=DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
int emuWidth = (int)(pixelWidth * EMU_PER_PIXEL);
int emuHeight = (int)(pixelHeight * EMU_PER_PIXEL);
Drawing drawing = new Drawing();
d.Wordprocessing.Inline inline = new d.Wordprocessing.Inline { DistanceFromTop = 130, DistanceFromBottom = 430, DistanceFromLeft = 260, DistanceFromRight = 330   };
d.Wordprocessing.Anchor anchor = new d.Wordprocessing.Anchor { DistanceFromTop = 0, DistanceFromBottom = 0, DistanceFromLeft = 0, DistanceFromRight = 0  };
d.Wordprocessing.SimplePosition simplePos = new d.Wordprocessing.SimplePosition { X = 0, Y = 0 };
d.Wordprocessing.Extent extent = new d.Wordprocessing.Extent { Cx = emuWidth, Cy = emuHeight };
d.Wordprocessing.DocProperties docPr = new d.Wordprocessing.DocProperties { Id = 1, Name = imageName };
d.Wordprocessing.HorizontalPosition h = new d.Wordprocessing.HorizontalPosition(new d.Wordprocessing.HorizontalAlignment("right"));

 d.Graphic graphic = new d.Graphic();
// We don’t have to hard code a URI anywhere else in the document but if we don’t do it here 
// we end up with a corrupt document.
d.GraphicData graphicData = new d.GraphicData { Uri = GRAPHIC_DATA_URI };
d.Pictures.Picture pic = new d.Pictures.Picture();
d.Pictures.NonVisualPictureProperties nvPicPr = new d.Pictures.NonVisualPictureProperties();
d.Pictures.NonVisualDrawingProperties cNvPr = new d.Pictures.NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = 2, Name = imageName };
d.Pictures.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties cNvPicPr = new d.Pictures.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();
d.Pictures.BlipFill blipFill = new d.Pictures.BlipFill();
d.Blip blip = new d.Blip { Embed = imageRelationshipID };
d.Stretch stretch = new d.Stretch();
d.FillRectangle fillRect = new d.FillRectangle();
d.Pictures.ShapeProperties spPr = new d.Pictures.ShapeProperties();
d.Transform2D xfrm = new d.Transform2D();
d.Offset off = new d.Offset { X = 0, Y = 0 };
d.Extents ext = new d.Extents { Cx = emuWidth, Cy = emuHeight };
d.PresetGeometry prstGeom = new d.PresetGeometry { Preset = d.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle };
d.AdjustValueList avLst = new d.AdjustValueList();
xfrm.Append(off);
xfrm.Append(ext);
prstGeom.Append(avLst);
stretch.Append(fillRect);
spPr.Append(xfrm);
spPr.Append(prstGeom);
blipFill.Append(blip);
blipFill.Append(stretch);
nvPicPr.Append(cNvPr);
nvPicPr.Append(cNvPicPr);
pic.Append(nvPicPr);
pic.Append(blipFill);
pic.Append(spPr);
graphicData.Append(pic);
graphic.Append(graphicData);
inline.Append(extent);
inline.Append(docPr);
inline.Append(graphic);
//anchor.Append(extent);
//anchor.Append(docPr);
//anchor.Append(h);
//anchor.Append(graphic);

drawing.Append(inline);

return drawing;
```

I think in OpenXML there is a property highlight text color.  How do I get that in C# code?

Comment: you may want to share your code so that others might point out where to fix it instead of saying "plz give me in c# code". also, as you have 2 questions, you should seperate them and open 2 seperate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't set the alignment of drawing directly. You place it in paragraph for example and set its property alignment.

this is the code I'm using:

```
public void AddImageParagraph(Drawing element, JustificationValues alignment = JustificationValues.Left)
{

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
    Justification justification = new Justification()
    {
        Val = alignment
    };
    paragraphProperties.Append(justification);
    Run run = new Run(element);
    paragraph.Append(run);
    paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties);
    mBody.Append(paragraph);
}
```